# printf in system call returns malformed output

Tags: linux, macos, kernel, system-calls, xnu

I'm  logging system calls in OS X using a kext, like so:

```c
int hook_read(struct proc *p, struct read_args *u, user_ssize_t *r) {
    /* get som params here... */
    printf("[IDEN] SYS_read called, %s, %d, %d, %d.\n", params);
    return read(p, u, r); 
}
```

This logs to `system.log`. The issue now is that if the `printf` load is high (many system calls are called), the output in `system.log` is often malformed:
`ID]SYS_readEN] callparam, 123, ed 123, 123` for example. The string is scrambled. If I use `kprintf`, which prints to a serial port, malformed logs never occur.

Any idea's what's causing this behaviour are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf`/`IOLog` uses a buffer for sending messages to userspace, where they're then logged to the system log. If you output a lot of messages, this buffer can get full before the logging daemon has a chance to clear it, and your messages will be truncated and start running into each other. (`printf`/`IOLog` will return as soon as the message has been submitted to the buffer, and will not wait for the daemon to receive it.)

Additionally, I'm not sure if kernel `printf/IOLog` is in any way thread-safe, so it might also be the case that calling it from multiple threads simultaneously causes race conditions. I'd have to check the source to be sure.

`kprintf` is fully synchronous and will block until your message has been transmitted on the serial port or submitted via firewire. It's also thread-safe. In the firewire case, the kprintf output is also buffered, so if you output a lot of messages, this can fill up too and cause truncation. The `fwkpfv` command lets you specify the buffer size using the `--buffer` argument though, so you can counteract that. The downside of `kprintf` being synchronous is that it can slow the system down considerably with a high volume of messages.

Comment: Thanks. Performance is not an issue as this is just for investigation purposes. So I have to use `kprintf`. Can I grab `kprintf` output somehow without using two machines/VM's? Ideally, I'd like to write kprintf output to a log file...

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can only use kprintf with serial port (mainly useful in VMs these days) or firewire. You could always build a custom userspace logging system using an IOSharedDataQueue or kernel control sockets instead of using printf.